# how to set dynamic height of a Collection View, the 'view' not the 'cells'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have embedded a collection view in another view and disabled the collection view's scrolling ability, what i want to achieve is similar to Instagram's profile tab.  However, I cannot figure out how should I set the height of the collection view in this case since the number of cells are dynamic.

I tried searching different solutions but most results are on changing the cells dynamically but not the collection view height itself. Is there any default/standard solutions for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the width you want the collection view to have (hopefully that is static), and request a layout:

```
collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0., 0., width, 0.);
[collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```

The calculated height of the collectionView will then be available at:

```
collectionView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: i want to set the dynamic height of collection view, depend on the number of cells ,please tell me

Comment: @RaviJSS: Please check my answer below if you are working with swift. If you are working in objective-c then go through http://stackoverflow.com/a/28378625/6325474. This answer will help you a lot.

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift** please follow below steps:

Declare a `CGFloat` variable in declaration section:

```
var height : CGFloat!
```

At `viewDidAppear` you can get it by:

```
height = self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize().height
```

Maybe when you `reload` data then need to calculate a new height with new data then you can get it by: `addObserver` to listen when your `CollectionView` finished reload data at `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        ....
        ....
        self.shapeCollectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old, context: nil)
    }
```

Then add bellow function to get new height or do anything after `collectionview` finished reload:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        let newHeight : CGFloat = self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize().height

        var frame : CGRect! = self.myCollectionView.frame
        frame.size.height = newHeight

        self.myCollectionView.frame = frame
    }
```

And don't forget to remove observer:

```
self.myCollectionView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue in swift.

Answer (score 2):

1) you need to set height constraint to collectionview in storyboard or xibs

2) make outlet of heightConstraint

3) and use this code while relaod collectionview

```
collectionViewHeightConstaint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewController, set the frame of the collectionView. For example:

```
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200);
```

Comment: the height of the collection view is dynamic, depending the number of posts the user created, just like instagram, so i can't make it to constant....

Comment: Usually there is a dynamic number of cells. But if you really want a dynamic height of collectionView, you can set its frame whenever your datasource's array.count changes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact you know the height of the cells and you know the number of cells on the screen.  I would...

```
self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, DEFINED_WIDTH, DEFINED_CELL_HEIGHT*Number of Cells);
```

or have I miss understood the question?