# Collection view cellForItemAt indexPath not getting called (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I created a collection view controller from story board, and set its custom class to `ItemCollectionVC`, the custom class of its cell to `ItemCell`, and set its reuse identifier to `Cell`

Here's my `ItemCollectionVC` class:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class ItemCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

var dataSourceItems: [Items] = []
var counterBuildItems: [Items] {
    let weaponItemArray = WeaponItems.weaponItems as [Items]
    let defenseItemArray = DefenseItems.defenseItems as [Items]
    return weaponItemArray + defenseItemArray
}
var freeBuildItems = WeaponItems.weaponItems as [Items]
var captureKrakenItems: [Items] {
    let weaponItemArray = WeaponItems.weaponItems as [Items]
    let abilityItemArray = AbilityItems.abilityItems as [Items]
    return weaponItemArray + abilityItemArray
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    switch self.presentingViewController!.title! {
    case "CounterBuildVC":
        dataSourceItems = counterBuildItems
    case "FreeBuildVC":
        dataSourceItems = freeBuildItems
    case "CaptureKrakenVC":
        dataSourceItems = captureKrakenItems
    default:
        break
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSourceItems.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
    cell.cellImage.image = dataSourceItems[indexPath.row].image
    print(dataSourceItems.count)

    return cell
}
}
```

When the collection view controller is presented, it's empty, what could cause the problem?

Comment: Have you check the count of your array and reload your collection view?

Comment: Where do you call `reloadData()` on the collection view instance?

Comment: @vadian I didn't call it, do I have to?

Comment: My bad, you don't have to, it's a `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: @MandeepSingh I checked it, there's no problem

Comment: @BrightFuture see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are pretty sure that the `dataSource` of the collectionView is connected to the viewController (it should be by default), then you should `reloadData()` because the collectionView reading from `dataSourceItems`. To understand the case, add a break point in `cellForItemAt` and add another one in `viewDidAppear` and check which one is called first?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    switch self.presentingViewController!.title! {
    case "CounterBuildVC":
        dataSourceItems = counterBuildItems
    case "FreeBuildVC":
        dataSourceItems = freeBuildItems
    case "CaptureKrakenVC":
        dataSourceItems = captureKrakenItems
    default:
        break
    }

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Before adding a meaningless comment, as I mentioned in the answer, add two breakpoints and check what will happen. Cheers up :)

Comment: But `viewDidAppear` gets called first, doesn't that mean there should be a problem without reloading data?

Comment: viewDidAppear called before cellForItemAt?!

Comment: @BrightFuture This not should happened :) make sure that I'm talking about viewDidAppear, not viewDidLoad. cellForItemAt should run before viewDidAppear (viewDidLoad the first method should get called), so dataSourceItems is still empty, i.e numberOfItemsInSection is 0; After calling viewDidAppear, dataSourceItems should contains data... that's the case

Comment: I know, but indeed break point stopped at `viewDidAppear` first

Comment: @Rroobb glad that you got it :)

Comment: my bad! this is because no cells to draw at the first time!! instead, add it to numberOfItemsInSection and check is it zero? recheck it after reloadData get called

Comment: It is 0 the first time `numberOfItemsInSection` is called, and 24 after `reloadData`

Answer (score 15):

One of three things caused this problem, pretty much every time I have encountered it, in a TableView or `CollectionView`:

1) Your `ViewController` is not the dataSource of your `UICollectionView`

2) `numberOfRows` or `numberOfSections` method returns 0

3) The height of your cell is 0, either due to constraint problems, or a `heightForCell` method being not/improperly implemented.

It's impossible to say which of these is your problem, and it's always possible that you've encountered something strange. Make certain that none of these is your problems, before exploring less likely options.

Comment: 1. This is a UICollectionVC, not a UIViewController; 2. Both items and sections are not 0; 3. I don't have any constraints

Comment: A UICollectionViewController IS a UIViewController, and a CollectionView has a UICollectionViewDataSource as its dataSource (I'm pretty certain that  your use of a UICollectionVC assigns your VC as the data source, though). I mentioned these, because I've encountered the exact problem you're having dozens times before, due to simple coding errors, and one of these has always been the cause. A cell with a height of 0 is always the toughest to debug, for what it's worth. If both numberOfSections and numberOfItems are being called, this is likely your problem.

Comment: Also, correction (sorry): it's the containing view height/size, that can be the problem, not the cell size. Here are a couple of related issues:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847069/collection-view-isnt-being-displayed-cellforitematindexpath-is-never-called
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668781/uicollectionviews-cellforitematindexpath-is-not-being-called

Comment: I think it could have something to do with layout, Xcode gives me a misplaced view warning, and I could never fix it by clicking fix misplacement

Comment: Update: it's actually @Ahmad's answer worked, thanks for pointing things out anyways

Comment: No problem! Looks like numberOfCells was returning 0, because the UICollectionView was drawing before your data (array) was loaded into the data source? Sorry I wasn't more specific about the causes, there, kudos to @Ahmad, for getting the right answer, and glad you've got your project working!

Answer (score 2):

Some things that you could easily miss if you use ***storyboard***

1) Don't forget that content in cell must have connected Top, Bottom constraint and 
content view must have height, by this cell will know to set height for cell. If you don't have these, cell height will be 0, and function cellForItemAt will never get called.

2) You can use cell layout to set dynamic cell and height for cell if you use this function:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: 
    UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->
    CGSize {return CGSize(width: 20.00, height: 20.00)}
```

Comment: Useful answer. Thanks Egzon.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you get the right number of sections in the numberOfItemsInSection method for the collection view.

If you are adding a flow layout to the collection view, remove the flow layout, and check if the collection view cells show now.

If they do, just adjust your collection view flow layout code it should look like this

```
let _flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
_flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
_flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = _flowLayout
```

you can set the inset to fit your use.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem by initializing UICollectionView properly like the following:

```
fileprivate let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
```

Comment: This actually worked for me. I was using `UICollectionViewLayout` instead of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Thanks

Comment: Why it doesnt work with UICollectionViewLayout?

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a problem with the collection view contentInset, try adding below code in your collection view sub class.

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

override func reloadData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        super.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your code in viewWillAppear, then it will work properly.
/*

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

switch self.presentingViewController!.title! {
case "CounterBuildVC":
    dataSourceItems = counterBuildItems
case "FreeBuildVC":
    dataSourceItems = freeBuildItems
case "CaptureKrakenVC":
    dataSourceItems = captureKrakenItems
default:
    break
}
}
```

Like this :-

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
     switch self.presentingViewController!.title! {
case "CounterBuildVC":
    dataSourceItems = counterBuildItems
case "FreeBuildVC":
    dataSourceItems = freeBuildItems
case "CaptureKrakenVC":
    dataSourceItems = captureKrakenItems
default:
    break
}
}
```

*/

Comment: When we create the class for UICollectionViewController, Xcode will automatically create this. You can create a class and check it.

Comment: Actually, from the tutorial it clearly told me to remove this, and before I removed it it didn't work as well

Comment: @BrightFuture, Please change the background colour of collection view and cell. And see whether your collection view and cell are created or not. I am also facing the same issue right now.

Comment: @MandeepSingh interesting method. The collection view is created, but the cell is probably not, as I can't see it.

Comment: I think @dylanthelion has a point, I am having some layout issues I guess, as Xcode gives me a misplaced view warning, and I could never fix it by clicking fix misplacement

Comment: @BrightFuture, My issue has been solved and my cells are shown properly with data. I can send you the demo if you want.

Comment: Can you put your code on the answer so future viewers can see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125828/discussion-between-bright-future-and-mandeep-singh).

Comment: @BrightFuture, Just use this code. It will surely helps you.