# UICollectionView not displaying, cellForItemAt and numberOfItemsInSection not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make an app which will display a popup with of devices with "right" or "left" names depending on whether left or right button was pressed. However, after I press left or right button, the popup appears with empty CollectionView. I colored it green to make sure that it's size is not {0, 0} and it isn't.

[Popup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKggC.png)

Also, I tried to make sure that cells are not bigger than the CollectionView, and it seems, that they are not. I can't put size restraints on them, though, so maybe they get resized or something.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQVTI.png)

I tried understanding and using solution for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847069/collection-view-isnt-being-displayed-cellforitematindexpath-is-never-called), but it seems that my situation is somewhat different. In this question cellForItemMethod was called, but in my case it wasn't and I've got no subclass of UICollectionView, which is, I guess, why I cant override intrinsicContentSize.

Here is the code for PopUpViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol PopUpDelegate {
    func connect(device: CollectionCell)
}

class PopUpController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    static let identifier: String = "PopUpController"
    
    var parentVC: ViewController?
    var left: Bool?
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
    var delegate: PopUpDelegate?
    var lastSelectedCell: CollectionCell? = nil
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of items in section called")
        if (left!) {
            return (parentVC!.leftDevices.count)
        } else {
            return (parentVC!.rightDevices.count)
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("cell for item called")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionCell
        print("left: ",  left!)
        if (left!) {
            cell.displayDevice(device: parentVC!.leftDevices[indexPath.row])
        } else {
            cell.displayDevice(device: parentVC!.rightDevices[indexPath.row])
        }
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.selectButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        cell.selectButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unselectedButton"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        cell.setSelected()
        lastSelectedCell?.setUnselected()
        lastSelectedCell = cell
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("parent has ", parentVC?.rightDevices.count, " items")
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    static func showPopup(parentVC: UIViewController, left: Bool){
        //creating a reference for the dialogView controller
        if let popupViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "PopUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpController") as? PopUpController {
        popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        popupViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        //setting the delegate of the dialog box to the parent viewController
        popupViewController.delegate = parentVC as? PopUpDelegate
        popupViewController.left = left
            parentVC = parentVC as? ViewController
            print("showing left popup: ", left)
        //presenting the pop up viewController from the parent viewController
        parentVC.present(popupViewController, animated: true)
        }
      }
    
    @IBAction func onConnectPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.connect(device: lastSelectedCell!)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onDismissPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate and datasource for the collection view in the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check again  leftDevices and rightDevices data passing between ViewController to PopUpController screen and conform delegate and datasources.

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```