# Determine collection view height inside table view iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, dynamic-sizing

I have a static table view which has `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for automatic sizing for cells. I want to insert a collection view inside a table view cell which also has dynamically sized cells. What is the correct way to return the height of collection view so that my collection view cells won't hide inside table view cell. I want to achieve like in the image,

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378625/4601900

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38426150/4601900