# How can I avoid these constraint errors?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

As shown in the image, we have a couple of problems in a storyboard concerning to auto layouts, we have, let's say, `StackView1` and `StackView2`. The problem I'm currently having is that `StackView 1` and `StackView 2` need to resize based on the content (`height >= 100` and `bottom space`) that's why it is in red, because `StackView 1 need constraints for: Y position` (same for `StackView2`).

We have a couple of bugs because of that, and I wanted to do it rightly. As the question above says,

1. How can I avoid these constraint errors?
2. or do I need to completely refactor this part of the project?
3. Which options do I have in that case?
4. Which is the most used approach in this case?

[image: Storyboard image]

This is a xib I create for each "device" we have, so I don't know the height of the `StackView 1`
[image: Xib image]

Comment: What kind of view you are holding within you stack views? A stack view can determine its height only if its children have an `intrinsicContentSize`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the views inside fit perfectly and the stackviews resize just fine also. But of course there is something wrong if the constraints are in red. Inside `Stackview 1` I have a xib with a title label and a collection view. Inside `Stackview 2` I have a series of buttons that show you more info.

Comment: It looks like sv1 can't calculate it's height, which is causing knock-on height errors throughout the view. Check you have top-to-bottom definite vertical constraints for the content of sv1.  Without seeing the "internals" of the SVs this is just informed guesswork though :)

Comment: The problem is likely within the collection view in the first stack view. A collection view does not have an intrinsic content size by default, therefore the stack view cannot infer its size. Here is a solution to add an intrinsic size for your collection view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115679/4127258

Comment: @Eilon should I delete the height constraint after that?

Comment: @flanker what do you mean? Could you refrase that please?

Comment: @Jalil the point I was trying to make was that it appears all the errors seem to stem from the top stackview not being able to work out its internal height (the vertical red bar).  Without that, all the other elements can't work out their vertical height either.  Therefore check that all of the top stackview's views have a definitive height, either through an intrinsic height or a heigh constraint.  It's hard to be specific without seeing the layout. Also if the stackView is just loading a single .xib (as I think you're previous comment implies) you'd probably be better off with just a UIView.

Comment: @flanker I updated my question with the xib, to show you a little bit more of what I'm doing

Comment: @Jalil the earlier comment suggests there is only one xib in stackview1.  Is this the case?

Comment: @flanker if you mean like, type of xib, yes there is only one type, but sometimes I instantiate a couple of the same but with different information